# Javascript insane memory woe with Array

Tags: javascript

Exhibit A:

```
var pt = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
console.log(pt[0], pt);
```

sometimes the log will spit out `0 [Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity, Infinity]`, but only when you do a SIX zeroes array for `pt`. If you do five zeroes then you get an array of five zeroes as *expected*. The big *clencher* is how pt[0] can occassionally be `0` and `Infinity` a the same time *confusion*

Steps to re-create the problem:

- Download the `Development` branch of [Flanvas](https://github.com/jrollins/Flanvas/blob/develop/src/flanvas.js)
- Make sure you place the folder in web-server directory (otherwise you will encounter cross-domain issues)
- Run the page `examples/loader-svg.js`
- Look at the console to see the mix-up I'm referring to.

*Notes

- The console log in question (Exhibit A) located in `src/flanvas.js` on line 2958
- The framework has recently undergone a "shload" of updates and you'll notice not everything works -- I am aware.
- I'm testing on `Mac OSX 10.6.8` and `Chrome 15.0.874.121`

If there are any problems with my instructions, please post back and I'll get to them ASAP. Thanks.

** Clarification of the question **

If I run `console.log(pt[0], pt);` then I expect that the first value from the array `pt` and `pt[0]` will be **identical**. That's not the case in my `Exhibit A`. Why not?

Comment: @harto If I run `console.log(pt[0], pt);` then I expect that the first value from the array `pt` and `pt[0]` will be **identical**. In this case it isn't. I'll add this to an edit as well.

Comment: Isn't this a question for the framework developer?

Comment: @Jackson - are you saying Exhibit A on its own is enough to demonstrate the problem? Or is it only a problem in the framework code (which presumably does other stuff with the array before and after the console.log)?

Comment: @Jackson, pt[0] will become 0, pt will become a reference to the array.  If console.log waits for a while before turning the array into a string, 0 will still be 0, but the array may have changed.

Comment: @Jackson: There are a few spots in that function, within the `switch` statement, where you overwrite `pt` in a loop. Not sure if that's the intention, but I'd start by looking there. Remember there is no block scope in JavaScript as I mentioned in [my answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8391980/376743). Perhaps it was your intention to overwrite.

Comment: @nnnnnn Exhibit A by it's self is just fine. Relative to it's block it is not fine, hence my confusion. @@James Clark That is probable, but seems highly unlikely. @@@RightSaidFred You sir, are on your game. I overwrite the same variable because I assume that will "reset" the variable and I'm in no danger of running into "old content". However, it seems like "old content" is in fact what is being displayed because JS is honoring rules that are either bizarre or new-to-me (likely the latter).

Comment: @Jackson: Yeah, overwriting the variable won't help. Since JavaScript is "pass by value", and the value `console.log()` gets is a copy of the pointer to the original Array, overwriting `pt` doesn't help because `console.log` is entirely unaware of `pt`. If JavaScript was "pass by reference", it would be a different story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`console.log()` isn't necessarily synchronous, so whatever code is causing the values to be `Infinity` is likely happening later.

If you want to see the Array values in their current state, you need to be sure to capture its *current* value somehow.

One way is to abuse JSON for this purpose.

```
var pt = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
console.log(pt[0], JSON.stringify( pt ));
```

Or since it's an Array of primitives, you could `slice` it.

```
var pt = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
console.log(pt[0], pt.slice());
```

To find the actual issue, you're going to have to follow `pt` along and see who's misusing it.

---

### *demonstration*

Here's a demo for illustrative purposes.

http://jsfiddle.net/J7tbB/

```
var later = Date.now() + 1000;

var arr = [0,0,0,0,0];

console.log( arr );

while( Date.now() < later ) {
    var len = arr.length;
    while( len-- ) arr[len]++;
}
```

*Note that this freezes your browser for `1000ms`.*

As you can see, it creates an Array with 5 members initialized at `0`, then immediately passes the Array to `console.log`.

Right after that you have a `while` loop that will run for `1000ms`, incrementing each member once for each iteration.

If the `console.log` was *synchronous*, you'd get your zeros. Instead you'll likely get something like:

```
[2811349, 2811349, 2811349, 2811349, 2811349]
```

---

Now if we change it so that it logs a `.slice()` of the Array, you'll see that you get your expected values.

http://jsfiddle.net/J7tbB/1/

```
console.log( arr.slice() );

// ...

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: That seems to be a quirk of Google Chrome.  I get all zeros in FireFox and IE.

Comment: @gilly3: That could be. I normally test in Chrome, and I've noticed this out of sync behavior in the past when passing objects to `console.log`.